# (C) Radix Sort array from text file

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, radix

I am attempting to get this queue-based radix sort to work, but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with it. It uses a text file as the input medium and throws tons of errors when I try to compile it and run it with the text file.

Any advice would be helpful at this point.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define MAX 10
#define SHOWPASS


//Compiled Using GNU GCC Compiler


void radixsort(int *a[], int n)
{
  int i, b[MAX], m = *a[0], exp = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    if (*a[i] > m)
      m = a[i];
  }

  while (m / exp > 0)
  {
    int queue[10] =
    { 0 };
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      queue[*a[i] / exp % 10]++;
    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
      queue[i] += queue[i - 1];
    for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      b[--queue[*a[i] / exp % 10]] = *a[i];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      *a[i] = b[i];
    exp *= 10;

    #ifdef SHOWPASS
      printf("\nPASS   : ");
      radixsort(a, n);
    #endif
  }
}


int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    if ( argc != 3 )
    {
  printf("Need two input parameters in the following order: \n 1. Input file path \n 2. Number of elements in file\n");
  return 0;
}
 int num_elements = atoi(argv[2]);
 int *input_arr = (int*) calloc (num_elements, sizeof(int));
 int i;

    FILE *fin; //File pointer to read input file
    fin = fopen(argv[1], "r"); //Initialize file pointer

for(i=0; i<num_elements; i++)
{
fscanf(fin, "%d", &(input_arr[0]));
}


radixsort(input_arr[0], i);


printf ( "\nArray before sorting: \n") ;

for ( i = 0 ; i < num_elements ; i++ )
printf ( "%d\t", input_arr[0] ) ;
printf ( "\n\n");
return 0;enter code here
}
```

Comment: `printf ( "%d\t", input_arr[0] ) ;` //0:fixed value

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of errors in your code. Firstly, the way you are taking input is incorrect.

```
fscanf(fin, "%d", &(input_arr[0]));
```

While taking input, the array input_arr is filled with a single input value at input_arr[0]. The rest of the input is over-written at input_arr[0].

Replace it with, `fscanf(fin, "%d", &(input_arr[i]));`.

Even you are displaying output in incorrect way.After sorting, the same output will be displayed num_elements times because of the following incorrect statement:

`printf ( "%d\t", input_arr[0] ) ;`

Again replace the above statement with `printf ( "%d\t", input_arr[i] )`.

As an impact of  following incorrect statement,

`fscanf(fin, "%d", &(input_arr[i]));` ,

your program experiences a `Segmentation fault`, since in function `radixsort`, you are iterating from 0 to n-1(Number of elements).

```
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
   if (*a[i] > m)
   m = a[i];
 }
```

As only a[0] is filled with input value and rest of the array(from a[1] to a[n-1]) contains a garbage value, you will get a runtime error while executing your code.

There are lot of other bugs too, which i had fixed. This is the perfect running code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define MAX 10
// #define SHOWPASS


// Compiled Using GNU GCC Compiler


void radixsort(int a[], int n)
{
    int i, b[MAX], m = a[0], exp = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        if (a[i] > m)
            m = a[i];
    }

    while (m / exp > 0)
    {
        int queue[10] = { 0 };
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            queue[a[i] / exp % 10]++;
        for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            queue[i] += queue[i - 1];
        for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            b[--queue[a[i] / exp % 10]] = a[i];
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            a[i] = b[i];
        exp *= 10;

#ifdef SHOWPASS
        printf("\nPASS   : ");
        radixsort(a, n);
#endif
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf
            ("Need two input parameters in the following order: \n 1. Input file path \n 2. Number of elements in file\n");
        return 0;
    }
    int num_elements = atoi(argv[2]);
    int *input_arr = (int *)calloc(num_elements, sizeof(int));
    int i;

    FILE *fin;                  // File pointer to read input file
    fin = fopen(argv[1], "r");  // Initialize file pointer

    for (i = 0; i < num_elements; i++)
    {
        fscanf(fin, "%d", &(input_arr[i]));
    }


    radixsort(input_arr, i);


    printf("\nArray before sorting: \n");

    for (i = 0; i < num_elements; i++)
        printf("%d\t", input_arr[i]);
    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is still a segmentation fault that dumps the core. How can I edit the logic of radixsort so that it runs correctly

Comment: @user2172359: I have tested your program for 10 different test cases. And its working perfectly. Check Here: http://ideone.com/rL6Rx9 . The program may fail for edge cases, that you have to figure out yourself.I have fixed the compilation error and few logical error, that were there. Please try to fix seg fault yourself(if it exists), and please accept the answer, if it was helpful. Thanks:)

Comment: Try running your program under valgrind. That will detect many classes of errors (such as your if statement depending on memory that has not been initialized) at runtime. If valgrind is not an option on your platform, try gdb or whatever other debugger is available.